# Copy MS SQL Server table to SQLite table

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sqlite, jtds

A little background: I am making an Android application that will remain offline most of the time. The application will need to sync with a MS SQL server database when it connects to wifi. The on-board database is SQLite.  I am also very new to Java/Android development so I apologize if I'm missing the obvious somewhere.

I am able to make transactions with MS SQL server quite well using the JTDS driver however when I am querying the MS SQL server, I end up with a ResultSet object that I have to loop through one row at a time.  Is there a tool/method out there than can simply insert all rows from a ResultSet into a SQLite database table?

I am currently using the standard:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> table = new ArrayList<>(); // a list of lists to represent a table
ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<>(); // a list to represent a row of the table

Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"); 

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

while (rs.next())
{
     row = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i = 1; i < meta.getColumnCount() + 1; i++) // load data into List
     {
         row.add(rs.getString(i));
     }

     table.add(row);
 }
```

From here I was going to loop through my list and add each row one by one to the SQLite database table. This seems inefficient to me. Was just looking for a better way to copy table from MS SQL Server to SQLite on an Android device.

Comment: Looks like a `SELECT INTO` could do the trick, quick and easy. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: @KlingKlang I appreciate the link but that is copying a SQL db table to another SQL db table.  I need to copy a MS SQL Server table into a SQLite table with the Android app being the medium.  From SQLite, I can't query a MS SQL Server database and "select into" it a new table.

Comment: What's not clear in `SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;` **[IN externaldb]**? You can query SQL Server from Android. And You can use SQLite as the end db.

Comment: Otherwise, you could export the SQL Server table to a **CSV** file and then import the same file in SQLite.

Comment: @KlingKlang Because 'newtable' and 'oldtable' are from 2 totally different types of databases on two separate devices.  I can't run a SQLite query from the Android app and query a MS SQL database with that query. I have to first get the data from the MS SQL Server, which will leave me with a JBDC/JTDS ResultSet object, as described in my post.

Comment: It's possible to have 2 different database connections, why not?

Comment: Anyway, you can always go the intermediate file ("CSV in the middle") route.

Comment: @KlingKlang I could convert the ResultSet to a CSV somehow I'm sure but wouldn't that just be extra overhead? Like I said, I can parse the ResultSet into a SQLite table but it seems inefficient. I think it would be just as inefficient to go from ResultSet to CSV to SQLite table.

Comment: @KlingKlang Though I do see a Linked Server option using an ODBC driver where I might be able to query MS SQL Server from SQLite: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/138787/is-it-possible-to-open-a-sqlite-database-from-within-microsoft-sql-server-manage) and [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3087/creating-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-sqlite-to-import-data/).  Maybe I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: Or the other way around. (Throwing an INSERT INTO command from SQL Server to SQLite)

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in which you can copy all the database objects from one DB, to another in java using **JDBC API**. Here is the link to the repo for code.

https://github.com/neerajparkashsharma/COPY-DATABASE-OBJECTS-FROM-ONE-DATABASE-TO-ANOTHER-JAVA/blob/master/CopyDatabaseObjects.java

:)